# ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.act

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-manifest, emulation

I have a problem...
I'm making a simple program about GIS, and when I'm trying to launch it from eclipse to my device, I get warning when I check the console.

> ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.warteg.GIS/.Splash } from null (pid=16196, uid=2000) requires null

and the program is not installed in my device, but when I try with emulator from eclipse, the program is launched.

Can someone solve my problem? Here's my manifest XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

  <activity 
        android:name="Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"></uses-library>
    <activity android:name=".Splash"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".FormPetunjuk"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".Peta"></activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 6):

your are registering Splash activity two times in manifest.xml so remove this one:

```
<activity android:name=".Splash"></activity>
```

Comment: yeah,,it's work,,,but the program still not installed in my device,,,or i'm must export it to .apk,,,???

Comment: just uninstall prev apk from device and installed new version of apk